# Problema al insertar en sqlite desde nodejs en tabla con llave foranea

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite

Estoy realizando unos ejemplos de usar sqlite desde nodejs, todo estaba saliendo bien hasta que realice un insert a una tabla con llave foranea, paso lo siguiente

intente probar un insert de prueba, usando un id que no existía en la tabla relacionada, al ejecutar la sentencia no genero ningun error y mayor sorpresa al ver que se habia insertado la fila aun sin existir el registro en la tabla relacionada.

Realice lo mismo desde la aplicacion DB Browser usando la siguiente sentencia

```
INSERT INTO addresses (idPerson, address, description) 
VALUES(100, "dir 01", "dir 01")
```

lo cual si mostro el error respectivo

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
At line 4:
INSERT INTO addresses (idPerson, address, description) 
VALUES(100, "dir 01", "dir 01")
```

Pero al realizar el mismo insert desde nodejs crea el registro en la tabla address, realmente busque si me faltaba activar algo desde el paquete de sqlite de nodejs pero por mas que he buscado no he encontrado indicios

esta seria la sentencia que estoy ejecutando desde la API realizada con nodejs

```
const DML_I_ADDRESS_PERSON = `INSERT INTO addresses (idPerson, address, description) 
VALUES(?,?,?)`;
```

gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Se requieren dos cosas: 1. Que _SQLite_ se haya compilado con soporte para llaves foráneas y 2. Activar el soporte en la aplicación, en tiempo de ejecución. Referencia: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable